# Upload Pdf document from ios devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, http, pdf

I want to upload a pdf document from ios devices to my Http server. I cannot store them into my app. I want a file browser should be open and user selects its pdf and get its name and upload to server.

Comment: Well what you want is like, reading a folder from your app, list all pdf, select one and upload to server. The First step to achieve this is to save the PDF file into a folder in your app, its simple download of file can be achieved by normal NSURLConnection.

Comment: No i want to get the all doc files stored on my device & then show them in a doc picker.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate - what do you mean by "all doc files stored on my device"..

To the best of my knowledge if you want to store docs in your iPhone, they have to be done by the apps.. There are various document/file manager apps out there in the store..

You can design/write custom view controllers that would behave as file browsers to the list the (pdf) documents stored in your app container...

Comment: No, there is no centralised storage for documents on ios devices. So I want to know how can I get all the document file list(just as file browser option) stored on my device. I want to upload the pdf document from iOS device on Http Server.

Comment: i am afraid it is not possible.. iOS doesn't allow us to scan another app's container..

Comment: So what is the way out?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to let the user pick a document, and then upload the contents with `NSURLSession`